# How to shift netcdf dataset relative to grid cell numbers with python?

Tags: python, netcdf4

I have a global map (Longitude, Latitude, Depth) as a netcdf file (size: 236,1440) and would like to 'shift' the longitudes from -180/180 to -270/90, so that cell number 0 = -270 etc (means that the Australian continent is located around grid cell numbers 0 to ~300). How can I do this with python? So far, I have

```
Bathy=Dataset('/path/to/file', 'r+', format="NETCDF4")

lon=Bathy.variables[u'x'][:]

lat=Bathy.variables[u'y'][:]

depth=Bathy.variables[u'z'][:]

lon=lon[:]-90

Bathy.variables[u'x'][:]=lon

Bathy.close()
```

But this only shifts the reference frame and not the actual grid (that means 0 Degree Longitude is shifted to West Australia etc.) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a way how to do this with np.roll:

```
Bathy=Dataset('/path/to/file', 'r+', format="NETCDF4")
lon=Bathy.variables[u'x'][:]
lat=Bathy.variables[u'y'][:]
depth=Bathy.variables[u'z'][:]

depth_new=np.roll(depth,360,axis=1)
lon_new=lon[:]-90

Bathy.variables[u'x'][:]=lon_new
Bathy.variables[u'z'][:]=depth_new
Bathy.close()
```

It shifts the depth values 360 grid cells along the axis 1 to the right (which is -90 Degrees Longitude in my case).